# button show div box and javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I need a button that the div codebox in my script
and also executes a javascript function

i have this code so far

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('codebox').style.display='block';">bekijk hier de code</button>
```

so right now it starts the div with the name codebox

but it also needs to start this function wich is in the init.js so the body._resize

```
$body._resize = function() {
                        var factor = ($window.width() * $window.height()) / (1440 * 900);
                        $body.css('font-sizeMMath.min(Math.max(Math.floor(factor * settings.sizeFactor), settings.sizeMin), settings.sizeMax) + 'pt');
                        $main.height(panels[activePanelId].outerHeight());
                        $body._reposition();
                    };

                    $body._reposition = function() {
                        if (skel.vars.isTouch && (window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180))
                            $wrapper.css('padding-topMMath.max((($window.height() - (panels[activePanelId].outerHeight() + $footer.outerHeight())) / 2) - $nav.height(), 30) + 'px');
                        else
                            $wrapper.css('padding-top(($window.height() - panels[firstPanelId].height()) / 2) - $nav.height()) + 'px');
                    };
```

hope you guys can help me fix this button

Answer (score 0):

there's a few errors in your code in the resize function that I haven't got time to fix as going out now. use you console and try to clean up the code a bit to make easier to debug. for instance this line

```
 $body.css('font-sizeMMath.min(Math.max(Math.floor(factor * settings.sizeFactor), settings.sizeMin), settings.sizeMax) + 'pt');
```

isn't right and is opening the strings in the wrong place right at the end and spelling mistakes and to be honest I haven't a clue what it's trying to work out but putting it in the snippet tool shows it's wrong cause the bracket and  semicolon at the end is being treated as a string. . better off doing

```
var myfontSize = blah blah calculations.
 $body.css('font-size', myfontSize+'pt');
```

```js
function pressed(){
  document.getElementById('codebox').style.display='block';
  body_resize();
  }
 function body_resize() {
   
   alert('in resize function');
   
                      
                    }
```

```css
#codebox{display:none;}
```

```html
<div id="codebox">Codebox</div>
<button onclick="pressed()">bekijk hier de code</button>
```

Comment: hi
when i putt the bottom code in my script i see it as text? do i need it in the <script> and </script> ?

when i do that my button doesnt work anymore?

Comment: put it in script tags at the bottom of your page just before the closing </body> tag

Comment: it says body resize is not defined

with this { it says unexpected end of input
and with this and the end } it says unexpected token }

Comment: how were you originally calling the resize function ?

Comment: i was not earlier but now i need it

Comment: right now
i have this for my code 

function Calc() {
     document.getElementById('codebox').style.display='block';
     
     };

Comment: the codebox is working

but i have this code

function Calc() {
     document.getElementById('codebox').style.display='block';
     
     };

but as soon as i putt $body._resize = function() in it i get unexpected token }

Comment: the $body._resize is in the init.js

Comment: edited the answer, you need to debug that function badly, quick look shows errors. over to you

Comment: all i want to do is if you want you can download my website
that in game1.html the white box goes down when i press the button because now the grey box is behind the white. when i press that button then rescale the browser. the white box goes down. but i also want it to work without resizing the browser all the time


Hope you can help

Link to my website download:

https://mega.co.nz/#!OUlRhKzY!kLtgsR_jl0OKkpBQ3TIDMDa8uGi2t9_dIVqgPrO2Y9I

Comment: your original question is answered, how to start 2 functions with button click, another way to put them both on the button `<button onclick="function_1();function_2();">click</button>` you have to do some work now, debugging your code...

Comment: the code works
in my website
but not that bit when i press that button the white box goes down with it